# Power BI connecting to REST service gets SSL error

Tags: rest, powerbi

I have a REST endpoint I developed on a server in my local network.  If I go to the URL in my browser (chrome) like so:

https://myserver-01/AR_CM_AutoReports/rest/AutoReport/GetAutoReport

then I see the Json in my browser so I know it works.  But when I try to connect from PowerBI desktop version it gets the error: Unable to connect - Details: The Underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

I tried to clear the SSL state in my Internet options but that didn't work.  Anyone else have and solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried to connect from another browser in another network environment? are you sure the SSL certificate is valid?

Comment: also make sure you are not using tls v1.0 or 1.1. some of the latest clients may not allow them at all.

Comment: how can i solve this?